# ¿Como hacer uso de render en datatable?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, php5, datatable

**Estoy teniendo dudas respecto a como utilizar render en data table.
Tengo una columna de estatus, lo cual en la base de datos se guarda como valor 1,2 y 3
lo que quiero que me muestre en mi columna estatus es que si el valor es igual a 1 muestre pendiente, 2 En proceso, y 3 terminado. Pero no logro como implementar el case. Espero puedan orientarme.**

```js
 tablaReportes = $('#tablaReportes').DataTable({
        "ajax":{
            "url": "bd/reportes.php",
            "method": 'POST',
            "data":{opcion:opcion},
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "folio"},
            {"data": "nombre"},
            {"data": "apellido"},
            {"data": "direccion"},
            {"data": "descripcion_domicilio"},
            {"data": "telefono"},
            {"data": "num_contrato"},
            {"data": "fecha_inicio"},
            {"data": "fecha_final"},
            {"data": "cuadrilla"},
            {"data": "estatus",
            "render": function(data){
                var status_name = '';
                switch(data)
                {
                  
                  case 1: status_name = 'Pendiente'; break;
                  case 2: status_name = 'En proceso'; break;
                  case 3: status_name = 'Terminado'; break;
                  default : status_name = 'Desconocido'; break;
                }
                return status_name;
                
              }
            },
            {"data": "observaciones"},
            {"data": "encargado_cuadrilla"},
            {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btnEditar'>Editar</button><button class='btn btn-danger btnBorrar'>Borrar</button></div></div>"}

        ]
```

Lo que quiero realizar es algo parecido a este ejemplo

```
<td>
                                        <?php
                                        switch ($dat['estado']) {
                                            case 1:
                                                $dat['estado'] == '1';
                                                echo '<span class="badge badge-danger">Pendiente</span>';
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                $dat['estado'] == '2';
                                                echo '<span class="badge badge-warning">En proceso</span>';
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                $dat['estado'] == '3';
                                                echo '<span class="badge badge-success">Terminado</span>';
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
```

Adjunto imágenes.
[image: Mostrar datos en datatable]
[image: BD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre esta solucion, no se si sea la mas viable pero no he podido implementarlo con un switch

```
if (data == 1)
                {data = "<span class='badge' style='background: red'>Pendiente</span>";}
            else if (data == 2)
                {data = "<span class='badge' style='background: orange'>En proceso</span>";}
            else if (data == 3)
                {data = "<span class='badge' style='background: green'>Terminado</span>";}     
            return data;
```